# How to fixed navbar and padding content in fullpage.js?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I want to fix navbar when mouse-wheel up or down.

First, I mouse-wheel down go to next page, I return the previous page with mouse up and the container seems not working correctly.

It lost padding-top I was set in CSS.

You can see the video I recorded:

https://youtu.be/2Ddh3ruyzWc

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage'],
      navigation: true,
      navigationPosition: 'left',
      navigationTooltips: ['Sản Phẩm Mới', 'Hoạt Náo'],
      showActiveTooltip: false,
      menu: '#menu',
      scrollingSpeed: 700
  });

});
```

```css
.section {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.contentfit {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.left-content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    background: url("http://www.studiometa.fr/assets/img/projets/94/idcampus__larger.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.right-content {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.9/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.9/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">BRAND</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">Sản Phẩm Mới</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Hoạt Náo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
    <div class="contentfit">
      <div class="right-content">
        <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing               elit. Incidunt nisi accusantium laborum inventore                 aliquid distinctio aliquam aut, officiis ratione a.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="left-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="contentfit">
      <div class="left-content">
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
        <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing               elit. Incidunt nisi accusantium laborum inventore                 aliquid distinctio aliquam aut, officiis ratione a.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is main minimal code from my source.

You mousewheel-down. Working. Continues mousewheel-up to know my issues.

I think all problem at line:

```
.section {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

I must padding-top to padding content. Because the `.nav .navbar` hiden content of `.section`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define

```
html.fp-enabled body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

and remove

```
.section {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage'],
      navigation: true,
      navigationPosition: 'left',
      navigationTooltips: ['Sản Phẩm Mới', 'Hoạt Náo'],
      showActiveTooltip: false,
      menu: '#menu',
      scrollingSpeed: 700
  });

});
```

```css
.contentfit {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.left-content {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    background: url("http://www.studiometa.fr/assets/img/projets/94/idcampus__larger.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.right-content {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li {
  color: #000;
}
html.fp-enabled body {
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.9/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.9/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">  
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">BRAND</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">Sản Phẩm Mới</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Hoạt Náo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section" id="section0">
    <div class="contentfit">
      <div class="right-content">
        <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing               elit. Incidunt nisi accusantium laborum inventore                 aliquid distinctio aliquam aut, officiis ratione a.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="left-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section1">
    <div class="contentfit">
      <div class="left-content">
      </div>
      <div class="right-content">
        <p>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing               elit. Incidunt nisi accusantium laborum inventore                 aliquid distinctio aliquam aut, officiis ratione a.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Work great with me. Thanks for your answer. Can you explain why do this? I think `.section` not different with `.html.fp-enabled body`

Comment: **fp-enabled is added to the html element when fullpage.js is enabled**, and in your case `<div id="fullpage">` doesn't include whole page (not contains menu). a `section` is just a section of the fullpage

Comment: Thanks for that. Before asking a question, I also tried with `#fullpage` and other element but not the success. So, your answer save my life. Thanks.